# Break does not wortk

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char words[1000][100], lowercase[100];
    int i, j, k, l, m, s, letternumber[100];
    for (i=0; i < 1000; i++){
        scanf("%s", &words[i][0]);
        if (words[i][0] == '\n'){
            break;
        }
        j=0;
        while (words[i][j++] != '\0'){
            letternumber[i]+=1;
        }
    }
    for (s=0; s < i; s++){
        for(m=0; m < letternumber[s]; m++){
            lowercase[m]=words[s][m];
        }
        for (j=0; j < letternumber[s]; j++){   
            words[s][j] = lowercase[m-j];       
        }
    }

    for (l=0; l < n; l++){
        for (k=0; k < letternumber[l]; k++){ 
        printf("%c", words[l][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

that's my code, i want the first for loop to when the first character of the line is newline but it instead goes on no matter the input

Comment: `scanf("%s", &words[i][0]);` -> `words[i]`, you are reading strings not individual characters.

Comment: the scanf conversion specifier `"%s"` will never ever write a newline (or a space, a tab, ...) to the corresponding string. I suggest you stop using scanf and use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: The variable `n` is undefined. How did you compile it? Plus, you gotta be more clear about what you exactly want to approach. Right now, it's an Enigma.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be aware that you are supposed to show code that actually reproduces the problem. That implies, that you have compiled it and verified that is shows the issue. Showing some code instead that you retyped from memory is a good way to introduce more errors or hide the errors you have in your real code.

Comment: Cleaned up the code (it was really this messy, not retyped from memory) and replaced scanf with fgets, it runs properly now, thanks for the advice

Comment: @Lundin, `&words[i][0]` and `words[i]` are the same thing (when a pointer is expected, as it is here).

Comment: @ikegami Yes but the magic number `0` isn't obvious why it is there, especially as the code goes on as `words[i][0] == '\n'`. That all suggests that the first character has some special, undocumented meaning in this case.

Comment: @Lundin, They're trying to check for an empty line. As such, `words[i][0] == '\n'` makes perfect sense too. The issue is that `scanf %s` doesn't read lines.

Answer (score 1):

> Break does not work

`break` works fine.  Yet `words[i][0] == '\n'` is never true as `scanf("%s", &words[i][0])` never saves `'\n'` in `words[]`.

The `"%s"` in `scanf("%s", &words[i][0])` does 4 things:

1. Read 0 or more *whitespaces* including `'\n'` from `stdin` and discard them.  Continue until a non-whitespace is found.
2. Read 1 or more non-*whitespaces*  and save them into `words[i]`.  Continue until a whitespace is found.  Return the whitespace to `stdin`.  Without a *width* like `"%99s"`, overrun is possible.
3. Append a `'\0'` to `words[i]`.
4. Return a 1 if some non-whitespaces were read, else return `EOF`.

---

**Use `fgets()`**

To read and save a `'\n'`, use `fgets()` as that is designed to read a *line* of user input.

```
    //scanf("%s", &words[i][0]);
    if (fgets(words[i], sizeof words[i], stdin) == NULL || words[i][0] == '\n') {
      break;
    }
```